# Naming a variable with a nested dictionaries value

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I am working on an assignment where the goal is to simulate a player moving between rooms in a text based game. I have it just about completed, but when I update the current_room variable the program is ignoring the updated variable info for the display section.
Example:
The program starts with current room as 'Great Hall' and the program runs just fine, but after it loops, the current_room being displayed is not changing to reflect the direction the player entered. Is there an issue with how I am re-assigning the variable?

```
#A dictionary for the simplified dragon text game
#The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }

player_move = '' # set player direction at blank value
current_room = 'Great Hall' # set starting room

# variables for text displays
direction_prompt = "Enter the direction you would like to go or " \
            "\nYou can type 'Exit' to end the game\n > "
error_prompt = "Not a valid entry!"
location_prompt = f'You are in the {current_room}\nThe directions you can go are:'



while player_move != 'Exit': # set game loop to continue until player enters 'exit'
    # display available directions
    available_directions = rooms[current_room].keys() 
    print(f'\n{location_prompt}\n', *available_directions) 

    # prompt a player to enter a direction (or quit game)
    player_move = input(direction_prompt).capitalize()  

    if player_move in available_directions:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][player_move]
    
    elif player_move != 'Exit':
        print(error_prompt)

    else:
        break
    
print('Game Over')
```

Comment: The `location_prompt` variable is made *once* when you create it, it's not going to dynamically update when you change `current_room`~

Answer (score 0):

If you format `location_prompt` *not* as an f-string, but just using a placeholder, you can leverage `.format()` to dynamically update it each time:

```
current_room = 'bedroom'
location_prompt = 'You are in the {cr}\nThe directions you can go are:'
for _ in range(2):
    print(f'\n{location_prompt.format(cr=current_room)}\n')
    current_room = 'kitchen'
```

Output:

```
You are in the bedroom
The directions you can go are:


You are in the kitchen
The directions you can go are:
```